# how to create dynamics columns in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

having a table with a date column format as number(20150101). How can I count how many days per months I have and create months as columns in a new temp table. For example if I have:

```
Date
20150101
20150102
20150201
20150302
20150304
```

I would like to return

```
Jan  Feb   Mar
2    1     2
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you store dates as numbers?

Comment: because that's how the customer gave me his data

Comment: But even if he gives you a `20150101` you could store it as a `datetime`(`2015-01-01 00:00:00`) or `date`. You can always display it in the same format but it makes it much easier and more efficient to use the native datetime type, for example if you want to use `YEAR`, `MONTH` or `DATENAME`.

Comment: you are right but that is my original data

Comment: Convert the data into a usable form, do the work on it that you need to do, then (if necessary) convert it back to the original form. Don't create unnecessary complications by clinging to an "original format" that isn't right for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( d INT )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 20150101 ),
        ( 20150102 ),
        ( 20150201 ),
        ( 20150302 ),
        ( 20150304 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   LEFT(DATENAME(mm,
                                      ( CAST(CAST(d AS NVARCHAR(8)) AS DATE) )),
                             3) AS m ,
                        COUNT(*) AS c
               FROM     @t
               GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(mm,
                                      ( CAST(CAST(d AS NVARCHAR(8)) AS DATE) )),
                             3)
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte PIVOT ( MAX(c) FOR m IN ( [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May],
                                          [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct],
                                          [Nov], [Dec] ) ) AS p
```

Output:

```
Jan Feb Mar Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec
2   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

To count only distinct dates:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( d INT )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 20150101 ),
        ( 20150101 ),
        ( 20150102 ),
        ( 20150201 ),
        ( 20150302 ),
        ( 20150304 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   LEFT(DATENAME(mm,
                                      ( CAST(CAST(d AS NVARCHAR(8)) AS DATE) )),
                             3) AS m ,
                        COUNT(*) AS c
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @t) t
               GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(mm,
                                      ( CAST(CAST(d AS NVARCHAR(8)) AS DATE) )),
                             3)
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte PIVOT ( MAX(c) FOR m IN ( [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May],
                                          [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct],
                                          [Nov], [Dec] ) ) AS p
```

Comment: that works but what about if I have the same date twice? How can I do a distinct count?

Comment: @cojimarmiami, didn't you want count of distinct dates? The first query will return 3 1 2. The second will return 2 1 2.

Comment: what about if rather than NULL I want to assign 0 to the months with no data? @GiorgiNakeuri

Comment: @cojimarmiami,     `SELECT  ISNULL([Jan], 0) AS [Jan], ISNULL([Feb], 0) as[Feb], ISNULL([Mar], 0) AS [Mar], ISNULL([Apr], 0) AS [Apr], ISNULL([May], 0) AS [May],
                                          ISNULL([Jun], 0) AS [Jun], ISNULL([Jul], 0) AS [Jul], ISNULL([Aug], 0) AS [Aug], ISNULL([Sep], 0) AS [Sep], ISNULL([Oct], 0) AS [Oct],
                                          ISNULL([Nov], 0) AS [Nov], ISNULL([Dec], 0) AS [Dec]
    FROM    cte PIVOT ...`